# javascript function return text to html

Tags: javascript, html, function

I found the following code snippet and am looking for some clarification on how it works, because it solves what I'm hoping to do. The variable 'html' is a string, which is returned form the function showCard, and is placed into the HTML code as a div. I'm able to replicate this however the string output is returned and starts with: "..." so the div isn't created, the string is simply moved into my HTML because the quotes remain outside the div.

```
function Card(suit, val, name, symbol)
{
        this.suit = suit;
        this.val = val;
        this.name = name;
        this.symbol = symbol;

    this.showCard =function showCard()
    {
        var html="";
        switch(this.suit)
        {
            case "hearts": suit_text = "&hearts;";
            break;
            case "diamonds": suit_text = "&diams;";
            break;
            case "spades": suit_text = "&spades;";
            break;
            case "clubs": suit_text = "&clubs;";
            break;
        }
        html="<div class='card " + this.suit + "'><div class='card-value'>" + this.symbol + "</div><div class='suit'>" + suit_text + "</div><div class='main-number'>"+this.symbol +"</div><div class='invert card-value'>"+this.symbol+"</div><div class='invert suit'>"+suit_text+"</div></div>";
        return html;
    }
}
```

Comment: `switch` is similar to a series of `if`s. Please be warned, `suit_text` is not being `var`d anywhere in the code you've shared here

Comment: What part of this code do you not understand?

Comment: It looks like it's being put into the DOM for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bz72wkrj/  How are you actually inserting the elements?

Comment: var html=""; just initialises the variable to the empty string. It could be rewritten to http://jsfiddle.net/6ja9sjL2/1/ if you do not like the var html... The suit_test is now a global var the way it is used

Comment: How do you call this function? Make sure to properly create a `Card` instance with `new Card(....)`, and to declare the variable `suit_text`.

Comment: @arcyqwerty I think my issue is how I'm putting it into the DOM. I'm using  

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(returnHTML()));

the createTextNode must be the issue, I'll need to use the way you did and be able to specify where the text is placed. Thanks


returnHTML();

Comment: @jfriend00 I'm confused about how to append the html variable not as a string, I think arcyqwerty answered this for me. I'm not sure how to specify where that appends to, but with time I'll figure this out.

Comment: You of course cannot append a TEXT node containing HTML without seeing the tags

Comment: @KM617 you either need to create it with _DOM methods_ instead of as a _String_, or parse it first using e.g. `.innerHTML`

Comment: Thanks, using the MDN API I built an element and appended a node using createTextNode, can anyone recommend a way to build a node without being a text node, so that what I append to the node won't contain quotes, and therefore not be a string?

Comment: The code you are displaying is less relevant than the code that is calling it and inserting it into the DOM

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple examples of how you might convert a *HTML String* to *DOM*

1. If you're expecting the *HTML String* to start with any content which is valid inside a `<div>`

   ```
   function str2dom(str) {
       var d = document.createElement('div'),
           df = document.createDocumentFragment();
       d.innerHTML = str;
       while (d.childNodes.length)
           df.appendChild(d.childNodes[0]);
       return df;
   }
   ```
2. If you're expecting the *HTML String* to start with `<doctype>`, `<html>`

   ```
   function html2dom(str) {
       return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
   }
   ```

If you're starting with `<body>` you may need to modify one of the above methods.
If your *HTML* is invalid you may get an *Error*

---

After using one of the above methods, you can append what you want to a node of your choice with `parent.appendChild(node_to_be_appended);`

---

If you're asking how to create a *Node* instead of a *String*, use the *DOM methods*, such as [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

```
function makeNode(tag, attribs, text) {
    var e = document.createElement(tag),
        k;
    if (attribs)
        for (k in attribs)
            e.setAttribute(k, attribs[k]);
    if (text)
        e.textContent = text;
    return e;
}

makeNode('span');
// HTMLSpanElement <span></span>​

makeNode('span', {class: 'foo', id: 'bar'});
// HTMLSpanElement <span class=​"foo" id=​"bar">​</span>​

makeNode('span', {class: 'foo', id: 'bar'}, 'hello world');
// HTMLSpanElement <span class=​"foo" id=​"bar">hello world​</span>​
```

Comment: I think the OP doesn't need a fragment, they just want to insert HTML directly

Comment: @JuanMendes it is a generic method to convert a _String_ to _DOM_ in a way that can be appended to the document easily

Comment: I know, it's useful, I'm just not sure if it directly addresses the question

Answer (score 0):

If you use `createTextNode`, your HTML will be treated as regular text. Easiest way is to update the innerHTML of a node.

```js
function Card(suit, val, name, symbol)
{
        this.suit = suit;
        this.val = val;
        this.name = name;
        this.symbol = symbol;

    this.showCard =function showCard()
    {
        var html="";
        switch(this.suit)
        {
            case "hearts": suit_text = "&hearts;";
            break;
            case "diamonds": suit_text = "&diams;";
            break;
            case "spades": suit_text = "&spades;";
            break;
            case "clubs": suit_text = "&clubs;";
            break;
        }
        html="<div class='card " + this.suit + "'><div class='card-value'>" + this.symbol + "</div><div class='suit'>" + suit_text + "</div><div class='main-number'>"+this.symbol +"</div><div class='invert card-value'>"+this.symbol+"</div><div class='invert suit'>"+suit_text+"</div></div>";
        return html;
    }
}

var card = new Card('hearts', 1, 'Hearts', 'heart-symbol');
var container = document.createElement('div');
container.innerHTML = card.showCard();
// We could insert the container div, but we don't really need it.
document.querySelector('div').appendChild(container.firstChild);
```

```html
<div>
  Insert content here
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks. I'm new to JS and completely forgot about simply putting the html return from showCard as the innerHTML. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create the outer div using `document.createElement` and then populate the rest of the HTML using its `innerHTML` property.

```
function Card(suit, val, name, symbol)
{
        this.suit = suit;
        this.val = val;
        this.name = name;
        this.symbol = symbol;

    this.showCard =function showCard()
    {
        var html="";
        switch(this.suit)
        {
            case "hearts": suit_text = "&hearts;";
            break;
            case "diamonds": suit_text = "&diams;";
            break;
            case "spades": suit_text = "&spades;";
            break;
            case "clubs": suit_text = "&clubs;";
            break;
        }
        html="<div class='card-value'>" + this.symbol + "</div><div class='suit'>" + suit_text + "</div><div class='main-number'>"+this.symbol +"</div><div class='invert card-value'>"+this.symbol+"</div><div class='invert suit'>"+suit_text+"</div>";

        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('card');
        div.classList.add(this.suit);
        div.innerHTML = html;
        return div;
    }
}
```

The returned `div` can then be passed directly to `document.body.appendChild` like so:

```
document.body.appendChild(new Card(...).showCard());
```

Note that using `innerHTML` can, in some cases, lead to security issues if you're not careful with the inputs.  Make sure that the arguments you use to create cards are sanitized if coming from the user!

As an additional note, you might want to consider including the append operation in `showCard` or changing the name of `showCard` to something that is more descriptive of what it actually does (i.e. `createCard`)